# Mensa IQ test question - squares and arrows in triangles

Tags: pattern, visual

I saw this online test and after going through the solutions I got confused for the explanation given concerning the correct answer to a question.

[image]

C is the correct answer and here is the reason they give:

[image]

> Here C is the correct answer.
> Opposing triangles are point reflections.
> Hollow circles and arrows are already point reflected in the centre position.
> Therefore the blank triangle must have a filled circle in the middle,
> so only B or C can be correct.
> The arrow is always clockwise in front of the filled circle,
> so C is the correct answer.

But should it not be counter-clockwise instead of clockwise? (The answer would still be C)

Source: [Mensa New Zealand](http://nzlweb.com/)

Comment: I would agree with you. Maybe it's just an error in typing up the answer.

Comment: Another error: The black arrows in the top right and bottom left triangles are not point reflections of each other, since the latter points to the centre of its triangle and the other doesn't.

Comment: If you are going clockwise around the triangle, it goes empty circle > arrow > filled circle > empty circle > arrow > filled circle > ..." The arrow is always in front of the filled circle.

Comment: Mensa rarely gives explanations, are you sure this is from them?

Answer (score 1):

C is indeed correct answer, and it is clockwise

> It is counterclockwise in triangle, but in whole picture it is clockwise like this:
>  [image]

"Reflections" are "random." So don't count on that. (But it is because of hexagon and you have only 3 things in it - not much space to do something else)
Also you should add some link or something to source.