# Which wedge completes the pattern? (Raven Matrices-like Question)

Tags: visual, pattern

[image]

Which of the listed options (a-d) correctly completes the pattern in the whited out portion of the hexagon? Treat the hatched wedge as if it is blocked from view.

Source: https://sifter.org/iqtest/

This question is similar to the one listed here [Mensa IQ test question - squares and arrows in triangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100597/mensa-iq-test-question-squares-and-arrows-in-triangles)

but slightly different (in the bottom left wedge).

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> Noticing that the triangles directly opposite of each other have the same symbol on the tip of the triangle, by elimination, we can rule that the black dot must be at the top of the triangle, so the answer is A.